# Configure IPTables

Tags: linux, iptables, squid

We have RHEL 5.0 squid proxy in our office.

Our LAN is 172.20.12.0 /24 n/w. Proxy ip is 172.20.12.4 /24 .

I want to share Internet through proxy.

Most importantly:

Suppose I have flushed the iptables, can you tell me what is the procedure from starting to configure iptables.

Keeping in mind that only 172.20.12.4/24 traffic is allowed and all other (except 172.20.12.8 and 172.20.12.9) should be blocked from my LAN. And all users browsers should have proxy address to get Internet failing to give proxy should not get Internet.

Answer (score 1):

On RHEL 5 run `system-config-securitylevel` or `system-config-securitylevel-tui` to get some basic firewall rules.

Check if you're happy with them:

```
iptables -L -n -v
```

Your exact requirements are not very clear. But assuming you are usings Squid's default HTTP port 3129 (on 172.20.12.4 which somehow has Internet connection) and you want 172.20.12.0/24 to access Squid, add this after you set up basic blocking with `system-config-securitylevel`:

```
iptables -N SQUID
iptables -A SQUID -p tcp --dport 3129 --source 172.20.12.0/24 -j ACCECPT
iptables -A INPUT -j SQUID
service iptables save
```

PS

Assuming 172.20.12.4 has conncection to the Internet there should be some NAT configuration on the router leading to the Internet as 172.20.12.4 is not routable on the internet. It is likely that other hosts on 172.20.12.0/24 could use this NAT too and have no need to use the proxy. If you don't want them to use NAT you have to accomplish that on the NAT router.